# My calf catches my derailleur when I pedal

Tags: derailleur

I wore cycling shorts for the first time since purchasing my Ridley Liz and I found that my right calf was catching on my derailleur to such an extent that I ended up with no skin left on my leg.  Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Either your calves are bigger than mine, or you ankle is twisting your leg closer to the bike than is normal. Might I assume you aren't using clipless (lock) pedals? You might try using some lock pedals, they will limit the range of twisting that you foot can do on the pedal.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are rather "splay footed" -- when you stand your toes are pointing outward to the sides.  This cause your calf to come closer to the derailer than for a "normal" person.  You can learn to not do this so much, or you can get "toe clips" or "clipless" pedals that limit how much your feet can twist, or you can get someone to change out parts of your crank for one that places the feet farther out (several options here, but not cheap).

Comment: Are you actually hitting the Derailleur, or is the cable sticking out and rubbing your leg? I tried on my way home today to make my calf come in contact, and there was probably close to 2 inches between my calf and the derailleur.  Even with big calf it seems like it wouldn't be very likely for this to happen, and if it did, your leg would probably contact the chaining as well, as the derailleur only sticks out a very small amount beyond the top chaining.

Comment: Can you get someone to take a picture of you in your bike showing your calf? I Agree with @Kibbee, the derailleur should only go about 1/4 of an inch or less over the big ring, otherwise the crank would hit it when pedaling...

Comment: Although the chaining turns with the crank arm so it wouldn't rub as much as the derailleur which is stationary.

Answer (score 3):

If you're bike is properly assembled, and fitted, then your problems rest not in the bike, but likely in your foot position and your pedal stroke.

First, I would have your bike fit assessed to determine if you're riding the right sized bike, and that the saddle is properly adjusted. If the bike is properly fitted, then you need to change the position of your foot on your pedal and how you execute your powerstroke.

One simple solution may be to switch to clipless pedals if you're not already using them. This will somewhat force you to place your feet on the pedals properly. Other than that what you need is physical training to train your legs to execute a proper stroke. Unless you simply have very large calves, it's likely that you have an improper balance of strength in the vastus muscles of your quad. You need to consciously train your leg not to come within proximity of your derailleur until your weaker muscles get stronger and you develop some muscle memory.

If the reality is that you simply have large calves, then your only solution may be to remove the front derailleur and upgrade your bike to a 1x11 speed. until then, you can try wearing compression sleeves or socks to protect your skin.